# Binary directory of executables defined with CMake + Conan

Tags: cmake, conan

I am using CMake where I have defined the paths of the output executables:

```
SET(CMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${BINARY_DIR})
SET(CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${BINARY_DIR})
SET(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${BINARY_DIR})
```

BINARY_DIR contains value: "/mnt/t/myapp/bin".
The problem comes up with Conan - executable files are not copied into ${BINARY_DIR} directory after using:

```
INCLUDE(${BUILD_DIR}/conanbuildinfo.cmake)
conan_basic_setup(TARGETS)
```

Any idea? What am I doing wrong?

---

#edit

conanfile.txt:

```
[requires]
Poco/1.10.1@pocoproject/stable

[generators]
cmake
```

Comment: It's not clear if you are consuming a package or creating one. If your executable is not there, probably it was not copies when packaging. Also, if you are using TARGETS, you have to use CONAN_PKG::<package_name>. Could you share more details, like your recipe, commands executed, log output, etc ...

Comment: The project is quite complex, so I tried to create a minimalist project.
This is strange because it works fine there...

conanfile.txt included (main post).

Comment: Poco/1.10.1@pocoproject/stable is deprecated. Use poco/1.10.1@ or poco/1.11.0@ from conancenter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the reason.

This macro redefines cmake variables:

```
macro(conan_output_dirs_setup)
    set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/bin)
    set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE ${CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY})
    set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELWITHDEBINFO ${CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY})
    set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_MINSIZEREL ${CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY})
    set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_DEBUG ${CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY})

    set(CMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/lib)
    set(CMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE ${CMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY})
    set(CMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELWITHDEBINFO ${CMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY})
    set(CMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_MINSIZEREL ${CMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY})
    set(CMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_DEBUG ${CMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY})

    set(CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/lib)
    set(CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE ${CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY})
    set(CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELWITHDEBINFO ${CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY})
    set(CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_MINSIZEREL ${CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY})
    set(CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_DEBUG ${CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY})
endmacro()
```

To fix that:

```
conan_basic_setup(TARGETS NO_OUTPUT_DIRS)
```